# Strange characters when reading data from mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding, utf

Am using mysql and php.

In my database i have column value like following.

```
PreaqueÃ§a o forno mÃ©dio (180ÂºC).
```

But when i retrieve it using php it shows below string.

```
Preaqueu00e7a o forno mu00e9dio (180u00baC).
```

Something is wrong with character encoding. Any ideas to fix it?

Comment: make sure all your systems use the right encoding (probably UTF)?

Comment: share code from where you retrieve and display  ?

Comment: your table config is belongs to like this  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

Comment: utf8_unicode_ci is my column collation

Comment: okay show me your select block

Comment: $sql="SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE id='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($sql); @Karthi

Comment: @jdoe don't post code in comments, *edit* your question instead to include additional information. also: **don't** use `mysql_` functions - they are deprecated and in PHP7.0 removed. use `mysqli_` or `PDO` instead

Comment: i am shocking :) @FranzGleichmann

Comment: If you are using mysql try mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8") after select query and if you are using mysqli mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8") and If you are using class and object of mysqli then use below

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "test");
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");

Comment: See "Mojibake" in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using json_encode to display the output from select query. That was causing the problem.

```
function my_json_encode($arr)
{
        //convmap since 0x80 char codes so it takes all multibyte codes (above ASCII 127). So such characters are being "hidden" from normal json_encoding
        array_walk_recursive($arr, function (&$item, $key) { if (is_string($item)) $item = mb_encode_numericentity($item, array (0x80, 0xffff, 0, 0xffff), 'UTF-8'); });
        return mb_decode_numericentity(json_encode($arr), array (0x80, 0xffff, 0, 0xffff), 'UTF-8');

}
```

Used this function instead of the default json_encode.And it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have two problems.

`Ã§` is Mojibake for `ç` and `Âº` is Mojibake for `º`.  For that, you need to check:

visible.)

- The bytes to be stored need to be UTF-8-encoded. Fix this.
- The connection when INSERTing and SELECTing text needs to specify utf8 or utf8mb4. Fix this.
- The column needs to be declared CHARACTER SET utf8 (or utf8mb4). Fix this.
- HTML should start with .

Hex `00e7` looks like the "Unicode codepoint" for `ç`, but it is unclear how you could have created that.

Let's start by doing `SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM ...` to see what got stored.  Also provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  (More details in [*Test the data*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) .)

After fixing the Mojibake issues and doing the HEX, start a new question.  (I fear that this thread will get too messy to keep.)